# What is a Quest Word™?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, wordplay, pattern, word-property

<sub>*In the spirit of the What is a [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aword+is%3Aquestion)/[Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aphrase+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463), a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aphrase+is%3Aquestion+user%3A463) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aword+is%3Aquestion+user%3A463) puzzles.*</sub>

The quest Ryan was on brought him to the final clue he needed: "If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a Quest Word™.
Use the examples below to find the rule."

| Quest Words™ | Not Quest Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| QUEST | ADVENTURE |
| TRIANGLE | SQUARE |
| ESTABLISH | CREATE |
| STRENGTH | INTELLECT |
| QUESADILLA | ENCHILADA |
| EQUALITY | CORRUPTION |
| TRIPLE | DOUBLE |
| STRIPES | DOTS |
| PEDESTRIAN | WALKER |
| QUEUES | LINES |
| SEQUITUR | SENSIBLE |
| PEST | NUISANCE |
| PROTEST | ACTIVISM |
| ASTRONOMY | STARGAZING |
| ASTROLOGY | HOROSCOPE |
| TRIAGE | PRIORITIES |
| EQUIPMENT | WEAPONS |
| CHEQUES | BILLS |
| RESTRAINT | FORWARDNESS |
| TRIM | HAIRCUT |

CSV Version:

```
QUEST,ADVENTURE
TRIANGLE,SQUARE
ESTABLISH,CREATE
STRENGTH,INTELLECT
QUESADILLA,ENCHILADA
EQUALITY,CORRUPTION
TRIPLE,DOUBLE
STRIPES,DOTS
PEDESTRIAN,WALKER
QUEUES,LINES
SEQUITUR,SENSIBLE
PEST,NUISANCE
PROTEST,ACTIVISM
ASTRONOMY,STARGAZING
ASTROLOGY,HOROSCOPE
TRIAGE,PRIORITIES
EQUIPMENT,WEAPONS
CHEQUES,BILLS
RESTRAINT,FORWARDNESS
TRIM,HAIRCUT
```

The puzzle satisfies the series' inbuilt assumption, that each word can be tested for whether it is a Quest Word™ without relying on the other words.

These are not the only examples of Quest Words™, many more exist.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A Quest Word™ ...

> ... contains at least one of the contiguous three-letter substrings of the word **EQUESTRIAN**: EQU, QUE, UES, EST, STR, TRI, RIA or IAN. Not Quest Words™ don't contain any of these three-letter sequences.

Evidence section:

> ```
> [QUE]ST            ADVENTURE
> [TRI]ANGLE         SQUARE
> [EST]ABLISH        CREATE
> [STR]ENGTH         INTELLECT
> [QUE]SADILLA       ENCHILADA
> [EQU]ALITY         CORRUPTION
> [TRI]PLE           DOUBLE
> [STR]IPES          DOTS
> PED[ESTRIAN]       WALKER
> [QUE][UES]         LINES
> S[EQU]ITUR         SENSIBLE
> P[EST]             NUISANCE
> PROT[EST]          ACTIVISM
> A[STR]ONOMY        STARGAZING
> A[STR]OLOGY        HOROSCOPE
> [TRI]AGE           PRIORITIES
> [EQU]IPMENT        WEAPONS
> CH[EQU]ES          BILLS
> R[EST]RAINT        FORWARDNESS
> [TRI]M             HAIRCUT
> ```

They are called Quest Words™, because ...

> ... "equestrian" has a quest in it, obviously.

Comment: I knew I should have come up with something harder. Well done!

Comment: Harder doesn't necessarily mean more interesting. I like the puzzle, but the many Qs and STRs are quite suspicious ...

Comment: Yeah, I was a bit concerned with that as well.